# get ray direction for voxel raymarcher

Tags: rust, raytracing, bevy, wgsl, raymarching

So i am aware there is already a lot of info on this topic but i am having trouble putting the theory into actual code.

I am making a raymarcher to march into an octree and get the color of the voxel the ray hits.
But i am having trouble getting the direction of the ray. I saw [this](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/8479/how-to-calculate-ray) but i dont understand how the code works.
im working with bevy on the cpu side, so using wgsl in gpu land.

this is my direction code now but it does not take into account where the camera is facing

```
fn ray_dir(x: f32, y: f32) -> vec3<f32> {
    let d = 1/tan(radians(screen.fov/2));
    let px = x + 0.5;
    let py = y + 0.5;
    let aspect_ratio = f32(screen.width) / f32(screen.height);

    let ray_dir_x = aspect_ratio * (2 * px / f32(screen.width)) - 1;
    let ray_dir_y = (2 * py/f32(screen.height)) - 1;
    let ray_dir_z = d;

    return vec3<f32>(ray_dir_x, ray_dir_y, ray_dir_z);
}
```

this makes the screen either full background or full voxel(all voxels are the same colour as of now)

so my **Question** is how do i get the direction of the ray for each pixel in wgsl?

--**edit**--

i have used the same code in bevy to debug where the rays go:

```
for x in 0..shader_screen.width / 100 {
        for y in 0..shader_screen.height / 100 {
            let y = y * 100;
            let x = x * 100;
            let ray_dir = ray_dir(x as f32, y as f32, shader_screen.clone());
            gizmos.ray(
                Vec3 {
                    x: 0.0,
                    y: 0.0,
                    z: 0.0,
                },
                ray_dir,
                Color::RED,
            );
        }
    }
```

```
fn ray_dir(x: f32, y: f32, screen: ShaderScreen) -> Vec3 {
    let d = 1.0 / ((screen.fov / 2.0).to_radians()).tan();
    let px = x + 0.5;
    let py = y + 0.5;
    let aspect_ratio = screen.width as f32 / screen.height as f32;

    let dir_x = aspect_ratio * (2.0 * px / screen.width as f32) - 1.0;
    let dir_y = (2.0 * py / screen.height as f32) - 1.0;
    let dir_z = d;

    let mut vector = Vec3 {
        x: dir_x.abs(),
        y: dir_y.abs(),
        z: dir_z as f32,
    };
    vector = vector.normalize();

    vector = Vec3 {
        x: vector.x * 15.0,
        y: vector.y * 15.0,
        z: vector.z * 15.0,
    };

    return vector;
}
```

and this would look like this: https://imgur.com/Gulniva
all seem to go in the same spot on the bottom left. But there is also a dot/line seen more towards the middle of the camera. i think that is because there are 2 cameras in the scene

--**edit2**--

i changed `1.0 / ((screen.fov / 2.0).to_radians()).tan();`

to `1.0 / ((screen.fov / 2.0).tan();`

this gave me this result: https://imgur.com/a/Hb06kim

--**edit3**--

in bevy i can use this

```
fn ray_dir_v3(x: f32, y: f32, camera: (&GlobalTransform, &Transform, &Camera)) -> Vec3 {
    let ndc_x = (x + 0.5) / RESWIDTH as f32;
    let ndc_y = (y + 0.5) / RESHIGHT as f32;
    let world_pos = camera
        .2
        .ndc_to_world(camera.0, Vec3::new(ndc_x, ndc_y, 0.1))
        .unwrap();
    let mut dir = (world_pos - camera.0.translation()).normalize();

    dir = Vec3::new(dir.x * 50.0, dir.y * 50.0, dir.z * 50.0);

    dir
}
```

to get this result https://imgur.com/a/I3sppl8

and then i use this

```
fn rotate_at_z(vector: vec3<f32>, a: f32) -> vec3<f32> {
    let x = vector.x * cos(a) - vector.y * sin(a);
    let y = vector.x * sin(a) + vector.y * cos(a);
    let z = vector.z;
    return vec3<f32>(x, y, z);
}
fn rotate_at_y(vector: vec3<f32>, b: f32) -> vec3<f32> {
    let x = vector.z * sin(b) + vector.x * cos(b);
    let y = vector.y;
    let z = vector.z * cos(b) - vector.x * sin(b);
    return vec3<f32>(x, y, z);
}
fn rotate_at_x(vector: vec3<f32>, c: f32) -> vec3<f32> {
    let x = vector.x;
    let y = vector.y * cos(c) - vector.z * sin(c);
    let z = vector.y * sin(c) + vector.z * cos(c);
    return vec3<f32>(x, y, z);
}
```

to rotate every ray in the direction of the `camera.forward()`

this makes the entirety move with the camera.
this has solved the ray direction problem, however because nothing is every easy, there still remains some problem with the raymarching that makes it not detect voxels untill the camera is inside the voxel volume

Comment: Have you tried drawing the ray dir as a color? That might help with debugging. I did so (copy-pasted your code, but put abs() around ray_dir_x and ray_dir_y) and got as expected, a magenta line (the X's red + Z's blue) in the X axis and cyan (Y's green + Z's blue) in the Y axis. The (0, 0) is not at the center of the texture though, It's near the top-right corner instead, idk why.

Are you sure that the problem is in the ray direction calculation?

Comment: im noticing that it only hits a voxel when the camera is inside the voxel volume, not when its outside. so it might indeed have nothing to do with the direction of the rays

Comment: i've done some debugging and edited the post